# Converting url pattern to Django 1.11

Tags: python

How do I convert the URL pattern below to Django 1.11

```
path('profile/<username>/settings', views.edit_profile, name='edit'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.11 uses [URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/) instead of path.

```py
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)/settings$', views.edit_profile, name='edit'),
```